# assistance with xsl transform of a xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

first at all .. i am totaly new to this and not a pro coder .. normaly i make small php sites.

I have a watercoolingsystem. The Watercoolingsystem has a xml output, it writes all collected data in a xml file wich will refreshed every x seconds.

Now i have also a G19 LCD Keyboard powered with LCDhost software .. this software can read XML files and shows the values.

Unfortunately LCDhost can interpret the Watercooling xml .. i have to rebuild the file.

I started to look around but my skills in XML coding is -100 :(

The File a have looks so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LogDataExport xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <name>Aquasite2012</name>
  <exportTime>2013-04-04T21:00:20.7286335+02:00</exportTime>
  <logdata>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.650</t>
      <value>24.72</value>
      <name>Sensor 1</name>
      <unit>°C</unit>
      <valueType>temperature</valueType>
      <device>aquaero 5</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.650</t>
      <value>46.63</value>
      <name>Sensor 2</name>
      <unit>°C</unit>
      <valueType>temperature</valueType>
      <device>aquaero 5</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.650</t>
      <value>29.68</value>
      <name>aquaero CPU</name>
      <unit>°C</unit>
      <valueType>temperature</valueType>
      <device>aquaero 5</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.650</t>
      <value>161</value>
      <name>Flow 1</name>
      <unit>l/h</unit>
      <valueType>flow</valueType>
      <device>aquaero 5</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.650</t>
      <value>149.7</value>
      <name>Flow 2</name>
      <unit>l/h</unit>
      <valueType>flow</valueType>
      <device>aquaero 5</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.650</t>
      <value>870</value>
      <name>Fan 2</name>
      <unit>rpm</unit>
      <valueType>rpm</valueType>
      <device>aquaero 5</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.650</t>
      <value>860</value>
      <name>Fan 3</name>
      <unit>rpm</unit>
      <valueType>rpm</valueType>
      <device>aquaero 5</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.650</t>
      <value>956</value>
      <name>Fan 4</name>
      <unit>rpm</unit>
      <valueType>rpm</valueType>
      <device>aquaero 5</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.363</t>
      <value>80</value>
      <name>Füllstand in %</name>
      <unit>%</unit>
      <valueType>percent</valueType>
      <device>tubemeter</device>
    </LogDataSet>
    <LogDataSet>
      <t>2013-04-04T21:00:20.164</t>
      <value>26.6</value>
      <name>Wassertemperatur</name>
      <unit>°C</unit>
      <valueType>temperature</valueType>
      <device>aquastream xt</device>
    </LogDataSet>
  </logdata>
</LogDataExport>
```

and i need a output like this:

```
<as2012>
  <LogData>
    <Date>03.04.2013</Date>
    <Time>17:03:39</Time>
    <Sensor1>19,90</Sensor1>
    <Sensor2>19,90</Sensor2>
    <Sensor3>---,--</Sensor3>
    <Sensor4>18,90</Sensor4>
    <Sensor5>21,90</Sensor5>
    <Sensor6>21,60</Sensor6>
    <Fan1Rpm>845</Fan1Rpm>
    <Fan2Rpm>939</Fan2Rpm>
    <Fan3Rpm>863</Fan3Rpm>
    <Fan4Rpm>16640</Fan4Rpm>
    <Fan1Power>100,00</Fan1Power>
    <Fan2Power>100,00</Fan2Power>
    <Fan3Power>100,00</Fan3Power>
    <Fan4Power>100,00</Fan4Power>
    <Led1Power>0,00</Led1Power>
    <Led2Power>0,00</Led2Power>
    <Flow1Hour>160,8300</Flow1Hour>
    <Flow1Minute>2,6805</Flow1Minute>
    <Flow2Hour>166,4000</Flow2Hour>
    <Flow2Minute>2,7733</Flow2Minute>
    <TubemeterLevel>255,00</TubemeterLevel>
    <TubemeterWave>255,00</TubemeterWave>
    <PowerSensor1>0,00</PowerSensor1>
    <PowerSensor2>0,00</PowerSensor2>
    <Aquastream1Voltage>0,0</Aquastream1Voltage>
    <Aquastream1Current>0</Aquastream1Current>
    <Aquastream1Power>0,0</Aquastream1Power>
    <Aquastream1Frequence>120</Aquastream1Frequence>
    <Aquastream2Voltage>0,0</Aquastream2Voltage>
    <Aquastream2Current>0</Aquastream2Current>
    <Aquastream2Power>0,0</Aquastream2Power>
    <Aquastream2Frequence>120</Aquastream2Frequence>
  </aquaero4LogData>
</aquaero4LogData>
```

i am trying to find a way but my knowledge is to low .. at the moment i have this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet

  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

  version="1.0">

 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="t">
  <xsl:for-each select="t">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="unit">
  <xsl:for-each select="unit">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="valueType">
  <xsl:for-each select="valueType">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="device">
  <xsl:for-each select="device">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value">

    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

    </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="@*">

    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">

      <xsl:value-of select="."/>

    </xsl:attribute>

  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">

    <xsl:copy/>

  </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so i removed the lines i did not need .. but i don´t know how to rename.
Can someony help me to restrukture the xml .. i need from each LogDataSet the name and  Value plu sall other nodes deleted.

from this:

```
  <value>29.68</value>
  <name>aquaero CPU</name>
```

to this :

```
<aquaero CPU>29.68</aquaero CPU>
```

thank you in advance

mic

Answer (score 0):

This template could get you started:

Few things to consider:

- XML Element names cannot have spaces, so we need to replace them
- XML Element names cannot have characters like %, so I had to replace it with translate function

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0'?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="LogDataExport/logdata"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Build your output file, set date and time and then recurse the rest
  of input doc -->
  <xsl:template match="logdata">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:element name="Date">
                  <!-- Grab the Date/Time from the first LogDataSet/t element -->
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(LogDataSet[1]/t,'T')"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="Time">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(LogDataSet[1]/t,'T')"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For each name element in LogDataSet create an element with that value
  and set the value to the content of the value element -->
  <xsl:template match="LogDataSet">
      <!-- remove spaces and % symbol from name value -->
      <xsl:element name="{translate(translate(name,' ',''),'%','P')}">
          <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity template recurse input document elements and attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```